# mySQL group by 3 columns

Tags: mysql

I have a query here that group by 3 columns and count the total rows

```
SELECT count(*) 
 FROM (
 SELECT date,bankName FROM table
 GROUP BY date,bankName,referenceNo
 ) a;
```

Basically, this query is used for pagination. I have two queries before this one.

I have 166,000 rows of data now and this query taking 1.23 seconds to return the result which is not nice to use when the data grows. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try a compound index on date, bankname, referenceNo

```
CREATE INDEX date_bankname_referenceNo ON table (date, bankname, referenceNo);
```